# PyQt5 QWidget.setGeometry() not working for QLabel

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a very simple app in PyQt5 for displaying and sorting images. I'm  new to Python and Qt in particular, and I've been having a few problems. I'm trying to display QPixmap images within QLabel objects, and they display properly. However, they're lined up in a row as default and I can't figure out how to move them.

(I know the code is terrible but I'm trying to get it working before I make it clean.)

Here is my code:

```
class ImageClassifier(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        mainImg = QPixmap("img.png")
        xmplImg0 = QPixmap("img0.png")
        xmplImg1 = QPixmap("img1.png")
        xmplImg2 = QPixmap("img2.png")
        xmplImg3 = QPixmap("img3.png")

        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        lbl.setPixmap(mainImg)
        lbl0.setPixmap(xmplImg0)
        lbl1.setPixmap(xmplImg1)
        lbl2.setPixmap(xmplImg2)
        lbl3.setPixmap(xmplImg3)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl0)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl1)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl2)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl3)

        lbl0.setGeometry(30, 30, 30, 30)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Fruit Classifier')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ic = ImageClassifier()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The `lbl0.setGeometry()` function isn't doing anything at all and I don't have a clue why. Does anyone know of a way to fix this, or a better way to set the position of a QLabel object?

Comment: Looks like you're setting a geometry that's smaller than the minimum size so the geometry is ignored.

Comment: Oh sorry, I added that a second before I posted in a bad attempt to fix it. Without that line it still didn't work. I'll edit to remove that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the following bullets.

- When you add something to a QHBoxLayout/QVBoxLayout... you also have to set the geometry of your BoxLayout as well, not just of one element inside it.
- Everything you throw inside a BoxLayout it will adjust to it's parent(BoxLayout).
- Try setting the geometry of all your elements.
- Try setting the geometry of your BoxLayout
- If still doesn't work try setting ".setFixedSize(_width,_height)" also for all elements & BoxLayout, as you need.

**[Update]**
Look what I'm trying to say. Better with a example:

If you use a BoxLayout the position of your objects won't obey what you want. It will follow the BoxLayout policy. You also passed (self) for the QLabels what makes the QWidget its parent. That's a mess.

Check it out the following code.
I have no BoxLayout and I just said who is my(Qlabel)'s parent. So I'll behave as my "daddy" says. So now you can move it along.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ImageClassifier(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.setFixedSize(500,500)

        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setFixedSize(50,50)
        lbl0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl0.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl1.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl2.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        lbl3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lbl3.setFixedSize(50, 50)

        lbl.setStyleSheet("""background-color: red;""")
        lbl0.setStyleSheet("""background-color: green;""")
        lbl1.setStyleSheet("""background-color: blue;""")
        lbl2.setStyleSheet("""background-color: yellow;""")
        lbl3.setStyleSheet("""background-color: black;""")

        lbl0.move(50,50)
        lbl1.move(100, 100)
        lbl2.move(150, 150)
        lbl3.move(150, 150)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Fruit Classifier')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ic = ImageClassifier()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's just a simple way to do it. You better create your own Label that inherit QLabel. And personalize as you wish.

Comment: JUST SOME TIPS. You can also use some others functionalities oferred by BoxLayout, as setSpacing(_space<int>). To set the space between items. Also setContentMargins(_left,_top,_right,_bottom) to set the margin of the whole BoxLayout as well. If you wanna set margins for each item so you use the setContentMargins in each of your elements(QLabel) ...

Comment: Thank you very much, but I didn't explain the question clearly enough. I actually don't need to resize the elements, I just need to move them. The setSpacing() function works, but I'm not trying to space them horizontally, I'm trying to move lbl0, 1, 2, 3 under the lbl object. setGeometry doesn't do anything, and as far as I can tell setContentMargins doesn't either. Feel free to download the code and try it out. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Here's my current code: https://paste.ee/p/Dc4KA

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was trying to say. Check it out again, I just updated it :D

Comment: And about the .setStyleSheet(""). Try to see the following link, it will help you a lot !! [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: Sorry forgot the link [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)
@YetAnotherQuack